# php parse xml from url

Tags: php, xml, parsing

http://api.hostip.info/?ip=87.14.94.152

From this link (xml) i am tried to retrive countryName and countryAbbrev like this:

```
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/?ip=87.14.94.152';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
$Country = $xml->gml['featureMember']->Hostip->countryName;
echo $Country;
echo 'BREAK HTML';
echo "-----";
echo "// "; var_dump($xml); echo " //";
```

but $Country is blank, any idea about?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should add the result of your `var_dump($xml)` to the question.

Comment: BREAK HTML-----// object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(5) "1.0.1" } } //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this not like an answer, but, just another way to do the same:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=87.14.94.152&position=true');

$arrayofdata = explode("\n", $data);
$country = explode(":", $arrayofdata[0]);
$count = explode(" ", $country[1]);

echo "Country Name: ".$count[1]."</br>";    //Prints ITALY
echo "Country Abbv: ".trim($count[2],"()"); //Prints IT
```

The position=true url part, it's just in case that you want to retrieve the coordinates.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/?ip=87.14.94.152';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

$fm=$xml->xpath('//gml:featureMember');
print_r($fm[0]->Hostip->countryName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The  `countryName` node is nested in a deeper level. You can use the [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method to access attributes with colon. Here's how you can get the country name:

```
$countryName = (string) $xml->children('gml', true)
                            ->featureMember->children('', true)
                                ->Hostip->countryName; // => ITALY
```

You could also use an XPath expression to retrieve the country name. This is easier:

```
$hostip = $xml->xpath('//Hostip'); 
$countryName = $hostip[0]->countryName;       // => ITALY
$countryAbbrev = $hostip[0]->countryAbbrev;   // => IT
```

Comment: Hi tenks in advance but $countryAbbrev return [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

Make a local copy of the xml and it will work.  Just tested this and got the data back:

```
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/?ip=87.14.94.152';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data) or die("feed not loading");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     protected function getCountryNameFromIP()
     {

        $ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
           )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $answerIP = @file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=4b585e37503a519a408dc17878e6ec04fa963e1b946c567722538d9431c2d5cb&format=xml&ip=$ip" ,false,$context);

        if(isset($answerIP) && $answerIP !="")
        {
            $theResJ            =   simplexml_load_string($answerIP);
            $last_login_ip_cn   =   $theResJ->countryName;


            /**
            *   $last_login_ip_cc   =   $theResJ->countryCode;
            *   $last_login_ip_rc   =   $theResJ->regionCode;
            *   $last_login_ip_rn   =   $theResJ->regionName;
            *   $last_login_ip_cp   =   $theResJ->cityName;
            *   $last_login_ip_lat  =   $theResJ->latitude;
            *   $last_login_ip_lng  =   $theResJ->longitude;
            *   $last_login_zip_code=   $theResJ->zipCode;
            */
        }
        else
        {
            $last_login_ip_cn   =   "";
            /**
            *   $last_login_ip_cc   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_rc   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_rn   =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_cp   =   "";
            * $last_login_ip_lat    =   "";
            *   $last_login_ip_lng  =   "";
            *   $last_login_zip_code=   "";
            */
        }

        return $last_login_ip_cn;
       }

I hope it helps you
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree.  I just tried both answers and got good results.  Here is the test code I just ran:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/?ip=87.14.94.152';
// $data = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
// $Country = $xml->gml['featureMember']->Hostip->countryName;
// echo $Country;
echo 'BREAK HTML';
echo "-----";
echo "// "; var_dump($xml); echo " //<br/>";
?><br/><?php
var_dump($xml->gml);
?><br/><?php
print_r($xml);
?><br/><?php
var_dump((string) $xml->gml->featureMember->Hostip->countryName);
?><br/><?php
echo $xml->gml['featureMember']->Hostip->countryName;
$Country = (string) $xml->children('gml', true)
                            ->featureMember->children('', true)
                                ->Hostip->countryName; // => ITALY
echo $Country;
$fm=$xml->xpath('//gml:featureMember');
print_r($fm[0]->Hostip->countryName);
```

and here are the results output:

BREAK HTML-----// object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(5) "1.0.1" } } //

object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { } 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 1.0.1 ) ) 
string(0) "" 
ITALYSimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ITALY )